# sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a job say somthing like X. If i want to give permissions to execute the X job to a user . what role I have to assign to the user. But the user should not be able to edit or delete or modify the job and this job is in share environment. no other should not prevlge to run the job X.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SQL Server Agent Proxies: [Creating SQL Server Agent Proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064.aspx)